# Perl Mechanize module session cookie issue

Tags: html, perl, automation, www-mechanize

I try to use the perl script to automate the interaction with a website.

I use module WWW::Mechanize to realize my design. But, the website [https] shows session expired.

Can anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: Can you post some code... and the site

Comment: soulSurfer2010 - I try to login to apple.com website and I redirect to https://store.apple.com/us/sorry/session_expired. Thank you.

Comment: Give us some more hints (such as non-working code) to help you.

Comment: Or a site where you experience the same problem.

Comment: Your best bet is to show us the complete code.

Comment: Dear all - I had posted part of code, please help.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to try to login to the same site via browser but with **Javascript disabled**.

If you'll get same error page this mean that some cookies (or some redirects) are added via Javascript so you need to add these cookies manually from your code.

Any way i recommend you to install HttpFox for Mozilla Firefox and record you login session after that you can find what's wrong with the target site.

Answer (score 0):

Did you

```
my $browser = new WWW::Mechanize;
$browser->cookie_jar({});
```

?

Comment: Flesk - Thank you for your help. I try your solution but I fail to do so. Also, this a https website. Thank you.

Comment: Mechanize working with cookies by default (so you don't need $browser->cookie_jar() at all)

Comment: @Tommy: I don't have an apple account, so it's hard for me to test. What's the response after your post?

Comment: Flesk - if you dont't mind, I can share one of my apple account to you.